# Passing a variable to a view/form in order to change it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I change the form based on which link is clicked?

```
link_to "Option A", form_path 

link_to "Option B", form_path
```

I want to be able the change the form based on if Option A or B is clicked. Like:

```
if option_a
    some hidden_fields
else if option_b
    some other hidden_fields
end

# rest of the form here
```

To clarity, the majority of the form is the same. Just some hidden fields are different.

Comment: Seems like a job for JavaScript. Most (if not all) DOM changes are executed with JS. You should probably have a fallback for disabled JS, but it can be adressed later.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass params variables to the `form_path` method:

```
link_to "Option A", form_path(option: 'a') 

link_to "Option B", form_path(option: 'b')
```

Assuming `form_path` is setup in the routes like:

```
resources :form
```

The above will make a URL that looks like: `/form?option=a`

Passing an arbitrary hash after any required arguments to any `*_path` helper method will add those key values to the query string.

Now in your form:

```
case params[:option] when ?a
    # some hidden_fields
when ?b
    # some other hidden_fields
else
    # no option specified
end
```

And that's it.

Note: `?a == 'a'`

Answer (score -2):

When you render a partial you can pass variables to it, for instance:

```
<%= render 'form', :option => 'Option A' %>
```

Then on the form you have access to the option variable:

```
<% if option == 'Option A' %>
```